# Why my command of bash shell is not working?

Tags: bash, shell

I add environment value in ~/.profile

```
export TEST1="abc"
```

I execute bash shell script go.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.profile
```

but result of go.sh is not working.(can't find TEST1 variable).

```
set | grep TEST1
```

Otherwise when I execute go.sh in command line, it working. (can find TEST1)
Why go.sh is not working?

Comment: Works for me, are you using set inside or outside the script. The script runs in a subshell so anything that is exported/sourced in it will be lost when it ends.

Answer (score 1):

When you *execute* your script, a new process is created with its own environment. When you get the prompt back, that script is finished, and you cannot access its variables.

You have to source your script:

```
source go.sh
```

If all you want is a shortcut for reading the profile, use an `alias`:

```
alias go='source ~/.profile'
```

Answer (score 0):

A script cannot affect the environment of its parent shell.

You can see the changes if you include the test in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.profile
set | grep TEST1
```

Or when you perform the `source ...` in your current shell

```
$ source ~/.profile
$ set | grep TEST1
```

Answer (score -1):

the command

```
set|grep TEST
```

should works even without $

If you're using bash, try to put your variable in .bashrc

in any case if you try to set the variable via command line it should works too.

```
bash-3.2$ export TEST1="abc"  
bash-3.2$ set | grep TEST1 
TEST1=abc
_=TEST1 
bash-3.2$ set | grep $TEST1 
TEST1=abc 
bash-3.2$ echo $TEST1 
abc 
bash-3.2$
```